# how to solve type constraint mismatch, C# to F#

Tags: c#, f#, covariance

I'm trying to implement some C# code as F# for a p2p application.. I must admit I don't have full understanding of the p2p implementation and I hope it is irrelevant for fixing the type problem.. All of the p2p library is implemented in C#.

*The C# implementation:*

```
public class TestMessage : Message
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var p = new Peer();
p.Subscribe(new Subscription<TestMessage>
{
    Callback = x => Console.WriteLine(x.Text),
});
```

The basic idea is that the 'p' peer now subscribes to messages of the type 'TestMessage', and then there is a similar method for publishing messages..
The signature for the 'Subscribe' method is:

```
void Peer.Subscribe(ISubscription<Message> subscription)
```

The definition of the ISubscription interface:

```
public interface ISubscription<out T> where T : Message
{
    ICachingOptions CachingOptions { get; set; }
    IContact Contact { get; set; }
    string EntitySet { get; set; }
    string Key { get; }
    string Topic { get; }
    Type Type { get; }

    void InvokeCallback(Message message);
    ISerializableSubscription MakeSerializable();
    bool PredicateHolds(Message message);
}
```

*The F# implementation:*

```ml
type Xmsg(m:string) =
    inherit Message()
    member this.Text = m

let sub = Subscription<Xmsg>()
sub.Callback <- fun (m: Xmsg) -> System.Console.WriteLine(m.Text)
let p = new Peer()
p.Subscribe sub
```

***The last line results in following errors:***

```
The type 'Subscription<Xmsg>' is not compatible with the type 'ISubscription<Message>'
```

and

```
Type constraint mismatch. The type 
    Subscription<Xmsg>    
is not compatible with type
    ISubscription<Message>    
The type 'Subscription<Xmsg>' is not compatible with the type 'ISubscription<Message>'
```

I have tried messing around with :> and :?> for upcasting and downcasting, -but with no success..

Of course I have tried to search for a solution, however, either there are none or I don't understand how to apply them for my problem...

Is there a fix?, or should I just give up and make a C# library project for it (and use that lib from F#)? :)

Comment: `p.Subscribe (sub :> ISubscription<_>)`?

Comment: Or even `upcast sub`...or `sub :> _`.

Comment: `void Peer.Subscribe(ISubscription<out Message> subscription)`?

Comment: yeh the interface has the 'out Message'

    [interface ISubscribtion<out T> where T: Message]

Comment: no luck with (sub :> ISubscription<_>) and (sub :> _)

Comment: Is the `ISubscription<out T>` interface documented somewhere? Could you show its definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ganesh says, F# doesn't support covariance, which means that you can't use an `ISubscription<DerivedType>` where an `ISubscription<BaseType>` is needed in F# code.  However, support for covariance is baked into the runtime, so you can probably get around this with a set of casts:

```
p.Subscribe(box sub :?> ISubscription<_>)
```

Here you're upcasting `sub` all the way to an `obj` and then downcasting back to an `ISubscription<Message>`, which ought to work.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I think it's wrong given your workaround - but here's the link to the feature request to add covariance to F#: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5663470-provide-covariance-contravariance-language-support