# Why aren't IDictionary<_, > keys compatible with derived types?

Tags: dictionary, f#, covariance, idictionary

```
type TypeA () = class end
type TypeB () = inherit TypeA ()

// "The type 'TypeA' does not match the type 'TypeB'":
let iDict : IDictionary<TypeA, bool> = [ TypeB (), true; TypeB (), false ] |> dict

let d = Dictionary<TypeA, bool> ()
// This is OK, though:
d.Add (TypeB (), false)
```

Why are IDictionary keys incompatible with derived types?

Comment: Bound to be a duplicate, but arrays in F# are not covariant - method overloads like add are though

Comment: Because `KeyValuePair<'Key, 'Value>` is not covariant on `'Key`?

Comment: Of interest: [Eric Lippert's Erstwhile Blog - keyword: Covariance and Contravariance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/tag/covariance-and-contravariance/) Note: The list is in reverse chronological order, so start at the end and work forward.

Comment: Of interest: [how to solve type constraint mismatch, C# to F#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23018081/1243762)

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the differences between the two approaches:

In the first case, you are creating a list:

```
[ TypeB (), true; TypeB (), false ]
```

This has type `(TypeB * bool) list`.

The [dict](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/extratopleveloperators.dict%5B'key,'value%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) function has type `seq<'Key * 'Value> -> IDictionary<'Key,'Value> (requires equality)`.

Consequently, applying the `dict` function

```
dict [ TypeB (), true; TypeB (), false ]
```

results in a value of type `IDictionary<TypeB, bool>`.

`IDictionary<TypeB, bool>` is not equivalent to `IDictionary<TypeA, bool>`, these are completely different and incompatible types, hence the compiler error.

If you wanted to initialise your dictionary from a collection of more derived types in this way, you'd have to do the upcast explicitly, e.g.:

```
let iDict = 
    [ TypeB (), true; TypeB (), false ] 
    |> List.map (fun (a,b) -> (a :> TypeA), b) 
    |> dict
```

---

In your second example, this problem never materialised because you originally created a `Dictionary<TypeA, bool>`.

You then use the `Add` method to add something of `TypeB` to the dictionary.  Since `Add` is a method, F# can perform automatic upcasting on the argument, such that your value of `TypeB` is upcast to `TypeA` automatically.